# Unable to signin using google provider

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Today I run my app and I am not able to signin but previously it was working.
Below the exception I got in logcat. How can I make this work please?

My project contains producflavor in case it will help finding the solution.

```
01-12 09:00:52.831 3668-5987/? W/Bundle: Failed to parse Bundle, but defusing quietly
     android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2545)
     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2471)
     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2374)
     at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2727)
     at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:269)
     at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:992)
     at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6702)
     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityLocked(ActivityStarter.java:341)
     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1096)
     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:5837)
     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:5642)
     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:176)
     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3612)
     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
    01-12 09:00:53.728 3668-3921/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=722, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
```

Please help

Comment: Are you testing your app on a Samsung device?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @AlexMamo Yes I am testing on my real device **Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge**. I made same test on **genymotion Nexus 7** but I am not able to signin also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem once when using the same device as you, a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge. I also tested on a few other devices but everything worked fine. For me, that was a Samsung Exception that I have ignore it. But to be sure, try to test it on other real devices. I also recomand you to take a look at SHA/Cert/Account/Signing, maybe it is something related. Make sure the server client ID is correct.

Try also to put app signing Key,
 details [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html), to OAuth 2.0 Client ID SHA-1 finger print instead of signed key which was generated by using keytool. If you have checked "Google Play App Signing" in Google Play Console, there is a possibility that the signed key will not work.

Verify your App signing Key in `Google Play Console -> App signing -> App signing certificate` and after that copy SHA-1 certificate fingerprint and paste to Google API console OAuth 2.0 Client ID.

Comment: Right now the app is in development. Do I need to sign the app before its works? Right now I do not have google android developer account also so I cannot access to the console. I am really stuck on this issue @AlexMamo

Comment: Sure, you need to create one. You need to access to Console. This is how it works.

Comment: Hello @alex-mamo After generating SHA-1 certificate fingerpring for each flavor and putting `google-services.json` under `src/paid src/free` Its work like a charm even using Galaxy S6 Edge. I generate the SHA-1 fingerprint using android studio. Lets say your first proposal is correct. Thank you